# Using an instance in a function

Tags: swift

I’m new to Swift so I’ve been using the Swift Playgrounds app. On level 2 “Two Experts”, I initialized two experts:

```
let expert1 = Expert()

let expert2 = Expert()
```

What I wanted to do was create a function and pass whichever instance into it, access it’s methods etc, something like:

```
func actions(who: Item, distance: Int, turn: String) {

for 0 to distance {

        who.moveforward()
}

   ff turn == “Left” {

    who.turnleft()

   } else if turn == “Right” {

     who.turnright()

}

}
```

Where who is expert1 or expert2.

I couldn’t find a way of doing this so had to write the same actions twice:

```
Func actions(who: String, distance: Int, turn:String) {

   if who == “expert1” {

      for 0 to distance {

      expert1.moveforward()

}   Etc

 if who == “expert2” {

      for 0 to distance {

      expert2.moveforward()

}   Etc
```

Is there a way of passing an instance into a function then perform certain actions if it’s of a particular class?

Comment: I tried to format your code, but some of the braces are still off. Please try to fix up the indentation.

Comment: why is everything starting with an upper case letter, `Let`, `Func`, `If`, `Else` and `For` - that looks weird as ****. Use `let`, `func`, `if`,  `else` and `for`.

Comment: This is a really sloppy question.

Answer (score 0):

Since your experts is of type `Expert`, then the `who` parameter in your `actions` method should be of type `Expert`, if I understand the code correctly. Then you don't need two functions for each of the `Expert`s. Let me know if I understood you correctly, and if it worked out.

**Update**
@Alexander mentioned that you can also have these methods in an extension on `Expert`, like so:

```
extension Expert {
    func actions(distance: Int, turn: String) {
        // Add method code here
    }
}
```

When adding the method in an extension, every `Expert` object can use the method. So you could write `expert1.actions(1, "Left")` or something like that. Here's a [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Extensions.html) to the official Swift Programming Language guide about extensions.

Comment: Better to remove the "who" parameter, and just make these methods in an extension on `Expert`

Comment: Yes, I agree, but I based my answer on the smallest change that would make the code compile since OP is new to Swift.

Comment: "since OP is new to Swift." That seems like an excellent reason to take a moment to teach them about extensions.